# How to change the input audio device for a SpeechRecognitionEngine?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to change input audio device of SpeechRecognitionEngine from the System.Speech.dll to something other than the default?

Most examples seem to just call the SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice function.

Comment: I too am trying to do this.  I want to have a drop down of available audio devices/microphones.  Can you give an example of how to use SetInpoutToAudioStream that grabs the stream directly from a specified microphone, and not from a file?